# How detailed is the app review process/feedback?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, appstore-approval

When an app is rejected by Apple's App Store review process, do they tell you all the issues that's wrong with the app? Or do they stop after finding the first issue that's wrong?

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Please remove it. If needed, alter your last question

Comment: ok, i altered the other question, i believe this one doesn't overlap anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the rejections I have seen cited a specific issue that needed to be resolved. Although I have heard about more general rejections that cite general inconsistencies with the HIG.

It is only recently (6 months or so) that they really started providing very much feedback at all, the more recent rejections have been very specific stuff. I saw an app last week that was rejected because the arrow on the popover did not line up correctly with the button when opening the popover the first time, subsequent openings did line up correctly.

As with any human process it all just boils down to what reviewer you get and what they feel like doing with your app that day. I know from usage statistics in one of my apps that the reviewer used it for 7 minutes before approving it so they couldn't have done too much in that time.

Comment: Thank you, so if let's say Apple comes back with a problem with issue A, and then you fix A.  and then they find B...  But both A and B existed in the original build...  Would you say that's common?

Comment: I haven't heard about that scenario but I couldn't tell you how often it happens, its a very black box...